# UIScrollView don't scroll to the end?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, contentsize

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    CGFloat w = self.contentScrollView.bounds.size.width; 
    CGFloat contentoffSetx = self.childViewControllers.count * w;
    self.contentScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentoffSetx, 0);
}
```

I have a few UIViews on the self.contentScrollView. But I cann't scroll self.contentScrollView to the  `self.childViewControllers.lastObject.view`  .

`self.contentScrollView.contentSize` no big enough??

Comment: There just isn't enough information here for us to help you out. There could be any number of reasons for shy your scrollview won't scroll to the bottom. Offset, content existing out of bounds, layout issues, have you created programatically or through interface builder, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    CGFloat w = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;

    CGFloat contentoffSetx = self.childViewControllers.count * w;

    self.contentScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentoffSetx, 0);
}
```